# C, String array wont deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a simple program trying to print out some arrays and calculations but when trying to use string array I keep getting the same Message

This is the String Array

```
char *names[]={"Armstrong","Burns","Cousins","Duggan","Evans",
    "Field","Garnett","Hadfield","Johnston","Lovett","McDonald","Petersen","Singh"};
```

Function and prototype

```
void printFunction(char*, int *, int *, int, int);

void printFunction(char* names, int income, int numMembers, int povertylevel,
    int totalavg) {

  char *avgInc = " ";
  if (income < povertylevel) {
    if (income + 5000 < povertylevel) {
      avgInc = "****";
    } else {
      avgInc = "***";
    }
  }

  else if (income > totalavg + 10000) {
    avgInc = "**";
  } else {
    avgInc = "*";
  }

  printf("%-11s %-10d %-8d %s \n", names, income, numMembers, avgInc);
}
```

Main call

```
printFunction(*names,income,numMembers, povertylevel, averageIncome);
```

Comment: Function declaration and definition has different parameters types. you need to either change function declaration `void printFunction(char*,int *,int *, int , int );` to use only `int` instead of `int *` or modify the function definition to have `int *`.

Comment: Also, the call to function should be like `printFunction(names,income,numMembers, povertylevel, averageIncome);` and not `printFunction(*names,income,numMembers, povertylevel, averageIncome);`, note that you need to pass the address of array `names`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function declaration should be something like this:

```
void printFunction(char**,int ,int , int , int );
```

Because you've got array of string arrays so 1st argument must be double pointer.
I'm not sure how you want print names but with pointer arithmetic:

```
*(names+i)
```

to print all names.